# How to create a new tab in odoo 13?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

Hi I want to create a new tab in the hr.contract.form. [image]

When I create a new group the xpath element I get the error message that the group is not added to the root element.
`ValueError: Element '<page string="Assignment Information" name="assignment_information">' cannot be located in parent view` When I create a new page and a new group then the fields just show up in the Contract Details tab and not in a new one.
This is my hr.contract.xml file. The fields are defined in the hr_contract.py file and appear ar they should, so that one should be fine.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="hr_contract_view_form">
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_contract.hr_contract_view_form"/>
        <field name="model">hr.contract</field>
        <field name="name">mycompany.hr.contract.form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <!-- Additional fields in the contract details tab -->

            <xpath expr="//group[@name='duration_group']" position="after">
                <group string="Tasks" name="tasks">
                    <label for="employee_tasks"/>
                    <div>
                        <field name="employee_tasks"/>
                    </div>
                </group>
            </xpath>

            <!-- Assignment Information tab-->
            <page string="Assignment Information" name="assignment_information">
                <group name="assignment_information">
                    <xpath expr="//group[@name='additional_assignment_information']" position="after">
                        <group string="Assignment Location" name="assignment_location">
                            <label for="assignment_location"/>
                            <div>
                                <field name="assignment_location"/>
                            </div>
                        </group>
                    </xpath>
                </group>
            </page>

        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

This is the hr_contract.py file:

```
from logging import getLogger

from odoo import models, fields

LOGGER = getLogger(__name__)


class EmployeeContract(models.Model):
    '''
    Extend hr.contract model to add custom fields.
    '''

    _inherit = 'hr.contract'


employee_tasks = fields.Text(
    string='Employee tasks',
    store=True,
    readonly=False,
    translate=False,
    help='Custom colon-separated (name: value) tasks assigned to the employee.'
)

assignment_location = fields.Text(
    string='Assignment Location',
    store=True,
    readonly=False,
    translate=False,
    help='Location of the freelancers assignment'
)
```

Thanks for taking a look at it!

Comment: My answer work for you?

Comment: yes it did! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add your new page wrongly.Try this

```html
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="hr_contract_view_form">
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_contract.hr_contract_view_form"/>
        <field name="model">hr.contract</field>
        <field name="name">mycompany.hr.contract.form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <!-- Additional fields in the contract details tab -->

            <xpath expr="//group[@name='duration_group']" position="after">
                <group string="Tasks" name="tasks">
                    <label for="employee_tasks"/>
                    <div>
                        <field name="employee_tasks"/>
                    </div>
                </group>
            </xpath>

            <!-- Assignment Information tab-->
       <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@name='your previsous page name']" position="After">
            <page string="Assignment Information" name="assignment_information">
                <group name="assignment_information">
                    <xpath expr="//group[@name='additional_assignment_information']" position="after">
                        <group string="Assignment Location" name="assignment_location">
                            <label for="assignment_location"/>
                            <div>
                                <field name="assignment_location"/>
                            </div>
                        </group>
                    </xpath>
                </group>
            </page>
</xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```